# How to call the right function (as a string) based on an argument?

Tags: python

I have a class which is intended to create an IBM Cloud Object Storage object. There are 2 functions I can use for initialization : resource() and client(). In the **init** function there is an object_type parameter which will be used to decide which function to call.

```
class ObjectStorage:

    def __init__(self, object_type: str, endpoint: str, api_key: str, instance_crn: str, auth_endpoint: str):

        valid_object_types = ("resource", "client")
        if object_type not in valid_object_types:
            raise ValueError("Object initialization error: Status must be one of %r." % valid_object_types)

        method_type = getattr(ibm_boto3, object_type)()
        self._conn = method_type(
                    "s3",
                    ibm_api_key_id = api_key,
                    ibm_service_instance_id= instance_crn,
                    ibm_auth_endpoint = auth_endpoint,
                    config=Config(signature_version="oauth"),
                    endpoint_url=endpoint,
        )

    @property    
    def connect(self):
        return self._conn
```

If I run this, I receive the following error:

**TypeError: client() missing 1 required positional argument: 'service_name'**

If I use this in a simple function and call it by using ibm_boto3.client() or ibm_boto3.resource(), it works like a charm.

```
def get_cos_client_connection():
    COS_ENDPOINT = "xxxxx"
    COS_API_KEY_ID = "yyyyy"
    COS_INSTANCE_CRN = "zzzzz"
    COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT = "----"
    cos = ibm_boto3.client("s3",
            ibm_api_key_id=COS_API_KEY_ID,
            ibm_service_instance_id=COS_INSTANCE_CRN,
            ibm_auth_endpoint=COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
            config=Config(signature_version="oauth"),
            endpoint_url=COS_ENDPOINT
    )
    return cos

cos = get_cos_client_connection()
```

It looks like it calls the client function on this line, but I am not sure why:

```
method_type = getattr(ibm_boto3, object_type)()
```

I tried using:

```
method_type = getattr(ibm_boto3, lambda: object_type)()
```

but it was a silly move.

The client function looks like this btw:

```
def client(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Create a low-level service client by name using the default session.

    See :py:meth:`ibm_boto3.session.Session.client`.
    """
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
```

which refers to:

```
def client(self, service_name, region_name=None, api_version=None,
               use_ssl=True, verify=None, endpoint_url=None,
               aws_access_key_id=None, aws_secret_access_key=None, aws_session_token=None,
               ibm_api_key_id=None, ibm_service_instance_id=None, ibm_auth_endpoint=None,
               auth_function=None, token_manager=None,
               config=None):
        return self._session.create_client(
            service_name, region_name=region_name, api_version=api_version,
            use_ssl=use_ssl, verify=verify, endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
            aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
            aws_session_token=aws_session_token,
            ibm_api_key_id=ibm_api_key_id, ibm_service_instance_id=ibm_service_instance_id,
            ibm_auth_endpoint=ibm_auth_endpoint, auth_function=auth_function,
            token_manager=token_manager, config=config)
```

Same goes for resource()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the stracktrace, it will probably point to this line:

```
method_type = getattr(ibm_boto3, object_type)()
```

And not the one after where you actually call it. The reason is simple, those last two parenthese `()` mean you're *calling* the function you just retrieved via `getattr`.

So simply do this:

```
method_type = getattr(ibm_boto3, object_type)
```

Which means that `method_type` is actually the method from the `ibm_boto3` object you're interested in.
Can confirm that by either debugging using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and inspect it, or just add a print statement:

```
print(method_type)
```